# Strange Error - Objects turning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use recursive functions to determine the greatest possible combination of values in a grid. One of my functions is acting quite strangely, giving me the error:

```
warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
```

my code for the function is as follows:

```
-(int)pattern4XBottomAtTile:(Tile *)t1 TileTwo: (Tile *) t2{
//base case
if(t1.x == t2.x && t1.y == t2.y){
    return t2.value;
}
//move 1
if((t1.y < 4) && (t1.y == t2.y) && (abs(t2.x-t1.x) == 2)){
    return t1.value + [self pattern4XBottomAtTile:t1.bottom TileTwo:t2];
}

//move 2
if((t1.x-t2.x == 2)&&(t1.y - t2.y > 0) ){
    return t1.value + [self pattern4XBottomAtTile:t1.left TileTwo:t2];
}
if((t1.x-t2.x == -2)&&(t1.y - t2.y > 0) ){
    return t1.value + [self pattern4XBottomAtTile:t1.right TileTwo:t2];
}

//move 3
if((abs(t2.y-t1.y) == 1)&&(abs(t2.x-t1.x) == 1)){
    return t1.value + [self pattern4XBottomAtTile:t1.top TileTwo:t2];
}

//move 4
if((t1.y == t2.y)&&(t1.x-t2.x == 1)){
    return t1.value + [self pattern4XBottomAtTile:t1.left TileTwo:t2];
}
if((t1.y == t2.y)&&(t1.x-t2.x == -1)){
    return t1.value + [self pattern4XBottomAtTile:t1.right TileTwo:t2];
}
return 0;
```

}

The problem that I have found so far, by use of multiple breakpoints, is that objects are being passed to the function, and are turning nil moments later.

A breakpoint at the start of the method shows:

[image]
[image]

When I run the function, however, I am met with the error:
[image]
[image]

On the left side of my screen, there is some information that might be relevant.
[image]

The values of t2 and t1 start as both nil at #4, and t1 changes to nil at #5.
The values do not change again until about 40264, in which t1 changes to the address of a tile and then changes again at 40265.

I am very baffled about where my problem resides. My recursive code was converted from working java functions provided by my friend, so I am a bit lost on all this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that many stack frames, you probably ran out of stack space (aka memory).  You need a better algorithm, or you have a bug and the recursion is not terminating when it aught.

Comment: 100% stackoverflow :) 39704 items in stack!

Comment: Put  "if(t1!=nil && t2!=nil){ }" around my functions and the error is disappearing. Now I have to figure out what is going on under the hood! Thanks